# Where is Galladite in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I know that in Pokemon X you can get Mega Stones after beating the game and some through the main story and Dianthus gives you a tali’s with Gardevoir, but where can you find Galladite?

Answer (score 5):

Pokemon X and Y do not have access to the full set of Mega Stones - some were introduced in Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.

Galladite is one such stone: it was introduced in Pokémon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire. It **cannot** be found in - or traded to - Pokemon X/Y.

Source: [Bulbapedia - Galladite](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Galladite)